# optimize lucene 4.6.1 for real time search

Tags: search, lucene, full-text-search, lucene.net

I know there are some similar questions, but as I searched through none of them is suitable to real-time searching.

my case is that I have over a few millions of small text files, for indexing I was able to achieve 3 mins per million files which is ok. The problem is for searching.

In order to get real time response, my search has to be as fast as possbile. currently, it returns result abount 8 - 10 seconds somehow. The query itself is kind of large though, but that should not be the major  reason.

when indexing, i have used following configurations

```
public static LogMergePolicy optimizeIndex() {
    LogMergePolicy mergePolicy = new LogByteSizeMergePolicy(); 
    mergePolicy.setMergeFactor(2); 
    mergePolicy.setMaxMergeDocs(50000);

    return mergePolicy;
}
```

and

```
IndexWriterConfig config =new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_46, analyzer);
        config.setMergePolicy(optimizeIndex());
        config.setUseCompoundFile(false); 
        config.setRAMBufferSizeMB(16);
        config.setMaxBufferedDocs(50000);
```

So any thoughts on how should I do to get real time response from search?

Comment: What does the query look like, and what analyzer are you using?  My guess is that some part of your query is slow, and you will need to do some work at index time to transform the data into a form that will support it better.

Comment: The query is simply text, but sometimes this text can be a hundreds words and it got transformed to tokens . Even though it should not be so slow. What do you mean by works at index? Can you give an example? Thank

Comment: I mean in analysis, mainly.  Some types of queries (leading wildcards is a common case) perform poorly unless you do the right kind of analysis to support them.